# Mysql не правильно делает выборку по диапазону дат

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Делаю вот такой запрос в phpmyadmin

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
 `ads`
WHERE
 (name <> "tmp" AND
  ads.reg_date >= "2016-06-20" AND
  ads.reg_date <= "2016-06-20") AND
 (`user_id`='126')
```

возвращает пустоту
однако если делаю вот такой запрос

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `ads`
WHERE
 (name <> "tmp" AND
  ads.reg_date >= "2016-06-20" AND
  ads.reg_date < "2016-06-21") AND 
 (`user_id`='126')
```

то отлично выводит одну запись... В чем дело, господа?

Comment: Не воспроизводится. Точно не срабатывают какие-то другие критерии? Поле reg_date какого типа?

Comment: reg_date типа timestamp

Comment: `reg_date` имеет значение `2016-06-20 00:00:00`? Именно к полуночи приводится строка даты без времени при сравнении с timestamp - дата со временем.

Comment: 2016-06-20 06:29:32 вот так

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ещё один вариант рассматривать временные рамки, а именно:
SELECT
  *
FROM
 `ads`
WHERE
 (name <> "tmp" AND
  ads.reg_date >= "2016-06-20 00:00:00" AND
  ads.reg_date <= "2016-06-20 23:59:59") AND
 (`user_id`='126')

Comment: Воспользовался вашим вариантом. Работает.

Comment: Перепроверил в mysql последняя секунда дня - всегда 23:59:59, их просто может быть несколько. Значение 23:59:60 невозможно, так что ответ корректен. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-leap-seconds.html На всякий случай напомню, что в минуте не всегда 60 секунд. Бывает и 61.

Answer (score 1):

По результатам уточнений в комментариях.

`reg_date` имеет тип данных `timestamp`. Значит, условие `reg_date >= :foo AND reg_date <= :foo` совпадёт только при совпадении всего значения, и времени и даты. И сравнивается не строка "2016-06-20", а строка "2016-06-20" после приведения к `timestamp`. Именно строка приводится к timestamp, а не timestamp усекается до даты и сравнивается со строкой. Дата без времени к `timestamp` приводится со временем полуночи, т.е. условие:

```
ads.reg_date >= "2016-06-20" AND
ads.reg_date <= "2016-06-20"
```

Планировщик рассматривает как

```
ads.reg_date >= "2016-06-20 00:00:00" AND
ads.reg_date <= "2016-06-20 00:00:00"
```

У вас, видимо, такого значения в таблице нет.
Довольно часто удобнее записать так, чем получать дату следующего дня на приложении::

```
ads.reg_date >= "2016-06-20" AND
ads.reg_date < "2016-06-20" + interval 1 day
```

Answer (score 0):

"2016-06-20" - запись подобного формата сводится к записи "2016-06-20 00:00:00". Получается, что единственная дата, которая удовлетворяет вашему запросу -  "2016-06-20 00:00:00". Попробуйте так:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
 `ads`
WHERE
 (name <> "tmp" AND
  DATE(ads.reg_date) >= "2016-06-20" AND
  DATE(ads.reg_date) <= "2016-06-20") AND
 (`user_id`='126')
```

DATE() - отсекает время, оставляя только дату.

Comment: Такой запрос работает. Проблема в том - как работает. Обращение `date(ads.reg_date)` исключает использование индекса по reg_date.